# Как собрать библиотеку написанную на c используя cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

Есть проект который написан на c++ использует. Есть библиотека которая написана на чистом c. Её тоже надо компилировать. Что надо написать в cmake файл чтобы он смнеил компилятор для данной папки?

Comment: Какой компилятор? Студия?

Comment: Компилятор mingw. Студия clion

Answer (score 1):

Вообще вы ничего не должны менять - компилятор подбирается сам. Тобишь для `c`файлов выберется компилятор `c`, а для `cpp` - соответствующий. Если у вас не определен компилятор `c` по умолчанию, то могут возникнуть определенные трудности, тогда просто в `cmake`файле добавте строку:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER my_compiler)
```

При этом `my_compiler` должен быть путем до компилятора, либо, если он дуступен из консоли, просто его именем.